# How to align text when typing shift+enter in draft-js?

Tags: draftjs

When my text has center or right aligment and press enter key no problem. But when typing shift+enter or alt+enter or ctrl+enter, the aligmnet is not working.

Image capture

[image: 1]

Anyone can help ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can use handleReturn to solve this,just like

```js
<DraftEditor handleReturn={handleReturn} />;

function isSoftNewlineEvent(e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
  return (
    e.which === 13 &&
    (e.getModifierState('Shift') || e.getModifierState('Alt') || e.getModifierState('Control'))
  );
}

// handleReturn
const handleReturn = (event: SyntheticKeyboardEvent) => {
  if (isSoftNewlineEvent(event)) {
    setEditorState(RichUtils.insertSoftNewline(editorState));
    return 'handled';
  }
  return 'not-handled';
};
```

Comment: You should format your code a little better by using back ticks ' ` '. Three of them at the beginning and end of code ``` code here ``` . Furthermore, you can add the programming language after the first three to get colour coding